# How to implement Canonical Tag in Pimcore CMS?

Tags: canonical-link, pimcore

I have to implement canonical tags on a customer website which works with Pimcore CMS. Does somebody has experience with that or can give me some hints?

Comment: Is this a Pimcore 5 project?

Comment: Hey, it ist pimcore in Version 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

A way could be to set a Document Property and render it in your view.
see: https://pimcore.com/docs/4.6.x/Development_Documentation/Tools_and_Features/Properties.html

For PHP Templating Engine you could add this line and set it properly in your Backend.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?= $this->document->getProperty('canonicalHref');?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I cant find a good tutorial to do this. I am a rly noob in Pimcore and I dont know where to put in your code snippet.

Comment: using TWIG it will looks like:
{% set canonicalUrl = document.getProperty('canonicalHref')|default(app.request.getUri??'') %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonicalUrl }}"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set this tag globally, or with some simple url regex matching, you can do it straight from the admin panel using Marketing > Tag & Snippet Management.

Answer (score 0):

To allow a user to customize URL you can create the predefined property 'canonicalHref',
then put in layout twig file:

```
<head>
....
{% set canonicalUrl = document.getProperty('canonicalHref')|default(app.request.getUri??'') %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonicalUrl }}"/>
</head>
```

You will still need:

- to customize HTTP headers in PDF files generated for the print version
- and to add 301 redirects from HTTP to HTTPS version.