# How to build a 404 error page in Pimcore v4.5?

Tags: pimcore

I want to build an 404 error page in Pimcore. How can I do that? The current website doesnt have one. Dont given URLs redirects to the homepage right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a document first under the document tree. Then go to Settings->System settings->Website and set that document as an error page. [image]
**Note** - The error page will only work when your debug mode is Off.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know an answer to this question about Pimcore? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754469/how-to-implement-canonical-tag-in-pimcore-cms

Comment: This took me a long time to get to the bottom of, but aside from debug mode, there's also *another* toggle, DEVMODE - and if that is enabled, the error page will not show.